# I've three waiting list tickets with status: WL3, WL4, WL5. Will all 3 get confirmed together?

Tags: trains, india, bookings, indian-railways

I have booked 3 tickets to Rajkot Express & its showing Waiting List 3,4,5.Will I get all my 3 tickets get confirmed & when does they get confirmed?

Comment: What country is this for?

Comment: This is for India, seeing the name of the train

Answer (score 11):

There's no guarantee that all passengers on your ticket will be confirmed.

The tickets can get confirmed any time, depending on cancellations, if any, by other passengers, who're traveling in the same class, as you have booked the tickets for. If you ticket gets confirmed, you will not know of the **Coach** and **Seat number**, till the **Reservation Chart** is prepared on the day of travel. Nonetheless, you will start seeing a status of **CNF** on your queries, which indicate that your ticket has been confirmed. You should keep checking the status of your ticket at [Indian Railways PNR status](http://www.indianrail.gov.in/pnr_Enq.html) website.

The reservation charts are prepared usually 2-4 hours before the scheduled departure of the train. The time varies for trains, but do not expect the chart before 4 hours anyhow. For early morning trains, the chart is usually prepared overnight.

In Indian Railways reservation system, a **Waiting List** ticket first changes status to **Reservation Against Cancellation (better know as RAC)** and subsequently it gets **Confirmed**.

Going by that, here are possible scenarios:

- The first passenger on your ticket, gets **RAC** and the others
  remain at **WL/1** and **WL/2**
- The first passenger is **confirmed**, while others are having status
  of **RAC**
- Two passengers are **confirmed** and one remains in **RAC**
- Two passengers get a status of **RAC**, while one remains in **WL**

Here is a short description, of what RAC stands for

> **RESERVATION AGAINST CANCELLATION (R.A.C.) :**
>
> The passengers whose names
>   figure under R.A.C., are provided reserved sitting accommodation
>   initially and are likely to get berths becoming vacant due to last
>   minutes cancellation of reservation of passengers not turning up in
>   time before the departure of the train,.